# Tipo de uma estrutura de dados Dicionarios

Tags: python-3.x, dicionário

Estou tentando contar a quantidade de dicionarios existe em uma lista. Porém a condição sempre da falso  no if.

```
>>> type(record['TranslationStack'][0])
<class 'Bio.Entrez.Parser.DictionaryElement'>
>>> record['TranslationStack'][0]
{'Field': 'MeSH Terms', 'Count': '506695', 'Explode': 'Y', 'Term': '"nucleotides"[MeSH Terms]'}
>>> type(record['TranslationStack'][0]) is dict
False
```

Comment: `Bio.Entrez.Parser.DictionaryElement` é referente a um elemento, item de um dict (lendo o nome) e não a um `dict`, que é um conjunto de elementos. talvez `type(record['TranslationStack'][0]) is Bio.Entrez.Parser.DictionaryElement` tenha mais chance de functionar.

Comment: Não deu certo. Retorna Falso

Answer (score 0):

Os elementos DictionaryElement são wrappers em relação ao tipo básico do Python dict, e se comportam praticamente da mesma forma, exceto devido a terem a propriedade 'attributes' que captura atributos XML.

O código abaixo deve funcionar:

```
str(type(record['TranslationStack'][0]))=="<class 'Bio.Entrez.Parser.DictionaryElement'>"
```